# why power function giving negative value?

Tags: c#, long-integer, integer-overflow

Currently I am implementing RSA algorithm. Following function is for power which we need in RSA.

```
private long power2(long x, long y, long n)
{
    long temp = 1;
    while (y > 0)
    {
        var z = y & 1;
        if (z == 1)
        {
            temp = ((temp % n) * (x % n)) % n;
        }

        x = ((x % n) * (x % n)) % n;

        y = y >> 1;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Here n is 9 character long(start with 6). **If I increase value of n(start with 9) then this function giving me negative** value for some value of x and y. I don't know why this is happening. As long can contain value upto 9223372036854775807 and In my power function there is no way multiplication go beyond this value.

And **what data type I have to use if I want to take n longer(10-15 character) then currently** I am using. I tried Decimal and double but its has same problem as above(giving negative value).

Comment: Why not post exact values of x,y,n on which you have a negative outcome, instead of vague descriptions ("some value", "start with 9")?

Comment: Did you try BigInt?

Comment: Because of overflow. *All* fixed-size types will overflow at some point

Comment: Try to use Big Integer
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For debugging calculations involving big numbers, in C# you can use `checked { /* yourcode */ }` to force exception being thrown on overflow. In your case you can then witness what happens. This has a performance impact, though, I don't recommend using it on a production scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening due to the [so-called overflow](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246946/Integer%20Overflows).

[Here is an article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) explaining why does that happen.

You may want [to use](https://www.dotnetperls.com/biginteger) [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) struct instead from `System.Numerics`.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution could still get beyond long values

you're multiplying the result of x%n (can be 10 chars long) with the same value which results something that could very well be more than 2^64 (before applying the last modulus, the result before the modulus should fit in a long variable as well)

consider using [`BigInteger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: _can be 10 chars long_ is not possible as n is 9 chars long

Comment: If I increase value of n(start with 9) then this function giving me negative - According to your question